# How can I export the *.bbl file after compiling with TexPad and using central *.bib file?

Tags: bibtex

I am using TexPad for Mac and I have a central `*.bib` file with my bibliography which is automatically generated using Mendeley. Everything works nicely, but now I want to send my colleague the bibliography (but not my entire `*.bib` file) of our joint work, i.e. the `*.bbl` file and I can't seem to find it anywhere, because TexPad takes care of all the auxiliary files so neatly that they are apparently nowhere to be found - anybody every had that problem?

Comment: I ran into this problem with one of my customers: She couldn't find the log files. texpad sas an option in "General Typesetting Options" call "hide intermediate files". Uncheck it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: Instead of sending the `.bbl` you can use `bibexport` (or similar tools) to create a slimmed down version of your `.bib` file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wanna convert your comment into an answer and get this question off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem with one of my customers: She couldn't find the log files. texpad has an option in "General Typesetting Options" call "hide intermediate files". Uncheck it.

Comment: This seems to no longer be an option in version 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal under the folder, and find the temporary files stored in `.texpadtmp/`.

```
ls .tempadtmp/
cp .tempadtmp/xxx.bbl .
```